# Reactjs: wait for parameters before requesting data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm using the flux pattern to retrieve data in a single call using a certain action which then gets passed on to the store. More details can be found below along with some pseudo code.

The scenario is as follows: components on the page pass a category parameter to an action, e.g. for retrieving labels during the componentWillMount method.

The code below will be called by different components on a page using a different parameter.

```
componentWillMount: function() {
   InitializeActions.addCategory('c1');
},
```

I then want to retrieve data from the server by making a single call with all the parameters (e.g. during the componentDidMount event).

```
InitializeData: function() {
   DataService.loadLabels(categories);
   //Dispatch loaded event to store
}
```

The problem is that not all parameters/categories get added before the initialize function gets called. How can I ensure that the parameters have been added before making the server call?

Comment: There's lots of different techniques for situations such as yours, but they all depend on more specifics. Perhaps add more code that shows your existing data flow.

Comment: This is a core concept to me as it seems logical to try and keep your amount of request to a minimum. I'm open for alternative techniques as well, I was just wondering if it could be achieved in such a way to get common data within a single call.